# Error in code using super

Tags: python

I am unsure why the code below results in an error. I am just creating a Sub-Class `Option` to the base class `Security` and try to use `super.get_description()` in the `get_description()` function which results in an Error.

```
class Security(object):
    def __init__(self, name, BriefDesc):
        self.name = name
        self.BriefDesc = BriefDesc

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.BriefDesc + ': ' + self.get_description()

    def get_description(self):
        return 'no detailed description.'

class Option(Security):
    def __init__(self):
        Security.__init__(self, 'Option', '(Derivative Security)')

    def get_description(self):
        return super.get_description() # Error here when print is executed. I am unsure why

    def study_security(security):
        print security   

print study_security(Option()) # Results in an error
```

Comment: You don't have a function named `study_security`, only a method in the `Option` class; you would need to write `Option.study_security(Option())`, or preferably `Option().study_security()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `super` and pass in the correct arguments<sup>1</sup>:

```
return super(Option, self).get_description()
```

Here is a link to the [documentation for `super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

---

<sup>1</sup>This last part is only necessary in Python 2.x though.  In Python 3.x, you can just do:

```
return super().get_description()
```